# Navbar from Boostrap 4 Conflicts with Metronic

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, metronic

I'm currently using 2 CSS templates on my project: one from Bootstrap 4 and the other one from Metronic. It looks like there's conflict between the two's CSS, so my `navbar` does not appear right. I already place Bootstrap CSS on top of Metronic CSS but my `navbar` is still not working properly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle.css" />
```

I already did the opposite things but it didn't change anything. Here's my source code for the `navbar`:

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary " >
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url()?>" style="margin-right:-80px">
  <img src="<?php echo asset_url()?>images/logosmkn.png" style="max-width: 50%">
</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url()?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/register">Pendaftaran</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/hasil">Hasil Seleksi PPDB</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/pengumuman">Pengumuman/Berita</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class=" nav-item">
      <?php if (isset ($_SESSION['nama_lengkap'])){?>
      <img src="<?php echo asset_url()?>images/user_m2.png" class="rounded-circle" style="max-width: 10%; float:right">
      <?php }?>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active ">
      <a class="nav-link href" href="<?php echo base_url()?>home/logout" ><?php 
        if (isset ($_SESSION['nama_lengkap'])){
        echo $this->session->userdata('nama_lengkap');
        }?>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[The issues with the `navbar`.](https://ibb.co/fdhqgw) When I removed the Metronic CSS the `navbar` worked fine.

Comment: You might want to specify what exactly you are referring to when talking about Metronic. If you are referring to a theme/template designed to work with Bootstrap 3, then of course, it's gonna conflict with Bootstrap 4. It that case that wouldn't be an issue for a question on SO but rather something for a support ticket with the vendor.

Comment: the template use the bootstrap 4 as well, yeah i already tried to contact them , waiting for their answer too

Comment: In other words, this is NOT a question for StackOverflow. This is a question for the template vendor.

Comment: thanks for reminding me ,  as like i said i already contacted them